# why double TimeoutInterval to avoid a premature timeout occurring for a subsequent segment that will soon be acknowledged?

Tags: tcp

I was reading a textbook which describes how TCP managing the retransmission timeout interval as:

TimeoutInterval = EstimatedRTT + 4 *DevRTT

***An initial TimeoutInterval value of 1 second is recommended. Also, when a timeout occurs, the value of TimeoutInterval is doubled to avoid a premature timeout occurring for a subsequent segment that will soon be acknowledged. However, as soon as a segment is received and EstimatedRTT is updated, the TimeoutInterval is again computed using the formula above.***

I don't understand why TimeoutInterval needs to be doubled, because each packet has its own timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP generally uses multiplicative back-off to slow transmission (assuming there is network congestion) and additive speed-up to increase transmission rate (assuming there is other traffic to contend with.)

Surprisingly, this isn't one of the more controversial features of TCP congestion control algorithms.  Wikipedia contains a good high-level comparison of various [TCP congestion control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_control) implementations.  This is a good starting point to learn about them.  You'll notice the authors of most alternative algorithms, in their own source code and academic papers, don't put a lot of weight on the function/multiplier used for back-off.

One reason for this is TCP gets other signals -- duplicate ACKs and SACKS -- to indicate that it should re-transmit segments.  RTO definitely happens in the practical world, but not as often as you might guess.